# Vagrant aborted at end of Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, vagrant

I've been having this problem for a while. Vagrant boxes abort at the end of a Jenkins job. I've limited the job to just a script with

```
vagrant up
sleep 60
```

For 60 seconds vagrant boxes are running, but the second the job finishes vagrant boxes are aborted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the [Jenkins process tree killer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). I got it to work by running Jenkins as follows:

```
java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins-1.537.war
```

Another (less global) work-around is to run vagrant as follows:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe vagrant up
```

Makes sense in retrospect. Processes launched by a Jenkins job should be cleaned up at the end. Of course this would be a "gotcha" is you're attempting to use Jenkins to launch long running processes.

+1 for this question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using an older version of the Jenkins plugin, but now it contains a checkbox called 'Don't Kill Me'. You have to check this to keep the vm up.

'[jenkins config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMAU4.png)'